# duplicate rows on specific value

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I need some help with the query to find duplicate rows on specific value. I have tried many queries, but I can't find it. For now I have this.

My sql structure:

```
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  vrijeme TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  pocetni_broj VARCHAR(55) DEFAULT NULL,
  zamjenski_broj VARCHAR(55) DEFAULT NULL,
  glavni_broj VARCHAR(55) DEFAULT NULL,
  postoji_zamjena INT(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

And my query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM zamjene_brojeva
GROUP BY glavni_broj
HAVING COUNT(glavni_broj) > 1
```

That is giving me all duplicate values in table. But how do I find duplicate values where column glavni_broj has value 966 45 19-68? I know that there is 4 rows with that value in glavni_broj. I have tried to put Where in that, but than query fails.

Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Please post a starting result set and desired result set

Comment: Could you please give some sample data and output of sample (actually what you want)

Comment: If I use query to list glavni_broj = '966 45 19-68' without having I get only one row, but I know that there is more rows containing that number. I would like to list all the rows with 966 45 19-68 in column glavni_broj.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so just include in your where what you want. the having will re evaluate and you should get your 4 records

```
SELECT *
FROM zamjene_brojeva
WHERE glavni_broj = '966 45 19-68'
GROUP BY glavni_broj
HAVING COUNT(glavni_broj) > 1
```

this will only return one row if you want all of the values then use group_concat() on your columns to see the values

start with a basic query

```
SELECT *
FROM zamjene_brojeva
WHERE glavni_broj = '966 45 19-68'
```

now if that returns rows look at how many come back. you can also figure out how many rows have `glavni_broj = '966 45 19-68'` by doing a count

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM zamjene_brojeva
WHERE glavni_broj = '966 45 19-68'
```

which will list each row where `glavni_broj = '966 45 19-68'`

**make sure that there is actually more than one row with '966 45 19-68' as the value**

Comment: It's not returning any results for some reason. I don't know why WHERE and HAVING are not working together.

Comment: @Budimir let me edit with some instructions to figure out whats going on

Comment: Rudell - Got it! I had a problem on other script which was inserting rows in that script. Thank you for the help. You pointed me to try and find problem somewhere else.

Comment: @Budimir glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

How come this does not help you ?

```
SELECT *
FROM zamjene_brojeva
WHERE glavni_broj = "966 45 19-68";
```

Comment: It return's one as result, but I need to list all the rows that are cotaining glavni_broj = '966 45 19-68'.

Comment: Then remove count(*). Use Select *

Comment: In that way I don't get all the rows that are having glavni_broj = '966 45 19-68'